# How to reset the Entry component to normal text after using the component for getting Password?

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords, tkinter-entry

```
pcount = 0;
def ready_password(self, event):
        self.pcount = self.pcount + 1;
        print(self.pcount);
        if self.pcount == 1:
            self.password.delete(0, END);
            self.password['fg'] = "#000000";
            self.password['show'] = "*";

    def reset_password(self, event):
        if self.password.get() == "":
            self.password['fg'] = "#D3D3D3";
            self.password.insert(0, "Password");
            self.password['show']="????????";
            self.pcount = 0;
```

I want the text to be displayed as normal text and not using echo character when I run the reset_passsword function. what value should be there in the place of question marks?

Comment: Try `self.password.config(show="")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty string should be in place of the question marks.

```
self.password['show']="";
```